# How to add a condition in template to detect super user is the same as post author

Tags: python, django

I am trying to something new in Django Project, I have different blogs made by users but I want to change the name of superusers or staff to become admin instead of their names. I have made a trial but it didn't work accurately I think the correct way would be similar.

Here is the template:

```
{% if post.author == user.is_superuser %}
<a class="mr-2 proj-title" href="">Admin</a>
{% else %}
<a class="mr-2 proj-title" href="{% url 'blog:user-posts' post.author.username %}">{{ post.author }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

Currently, all users' name appears either superuser or normal users.

Question how can I check is the post.author is a superuser or staff and if staff the name should be admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test if the Author is a superuser and you are using the built in Django User Model from `django.contrib.auth.models` as FK to `post.author` then just do:

```
{% if post.author.is_superuser %}
...
{% endif %}
```